# Connect to Bluetooth device with Bluetooth address

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I have a two way radio with a bluetooth board installed. Currently the radio is set to connect with proprietary motorola devices using a low frequency pairing system so the field user does not have to deal with the classic bluetooth connection process. I, however, am trying to connect the radio to my computer so I can program the unit. Since I cannot throw the unit into discovery/visible mode, I can not connect the classic way.

I know the radio's bluetooth address (shown in the radio menu) AND all the bluetooth protocol info (I have an identical radio already connected). Is there a way to connect to this radio in windows knowing this information?

Comment: If you can provide more information about the device, target windows platform, target bluetooth stack, target development tools, etc.It would be easier to provide assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use 32feet.NET library to connect to your device,  since you have all the information about the device. Assuming you are connecting to an RFCOMM device and want to get a stream then you could do the following:

```
using InTheHand.Net;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;        

...
...
//Somewhere in your connect function
//Replace with your mac address
BluetoothAddress addr = new BluetoothAddress(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });
//Replace with the service class of your device.  
Guid serviceClass = BluetoothService.SerialPort;
var ep = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, serviceClass);
var cli = new BluetoothClient();
cli.Connect(ep);
Stream peerStream = cli.GetStream();
```

At this stage you would have a stream to your device.

I am not sure there is enough information as the question does not mention which Bluetooth stack and targets are being used. Additionally we don't know about your device.

If your device requires out of band pairing you will need to target windows 8.1 or later.

Good Luck!